# How long does it take for an account delete request to be processed

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

Just out of curiosity, how long does it take for an account delete request to be processed?

Comment: Not sure, but be sure to give it a few business days.

Comment: @Pekka Thanks! If it does not get processed in 2 business days, I will contact them directly.

Comment: Why the hurry? Give it some time. It will happen at some point. (Or rather...don't leave)

Comment: :s Always a shame to see someone go who contributed well... Question though @robert does "please delete me" in one profile page suffice? I noticed he had not written the same in his other profile pages. I assume it's enough for verification, but am just wondering.

Comment: @Bart changing your profile to "please delete me" confirms that the person requesting deletion actually is the person using the account

Comment: @Bart: Normally I leave these for SE to handle, since such requests come from the same email address that is listed in the account, which provides a verification that the account has not been compromised.  This account only had two posts on it, so it's not like much is being lost.  In retrospect, SE has to deal with the email anyway (and the account is no longer searchable), so I'm probably costing them more time than I am saving.

Comment: @BenBrocka Yeah, I know and that's what I expected. I was just wondering if one profile page was enough.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not calling your action into question at all.

Comment: @Bart: I only deleted the account that said "please delete me."  I didn't touch the others.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ah, that's what I was wondering.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, it usually gets done within 2 days. However, please be patient and wait up to 7 days before contacting support again to delete your account.

Always make sure to follow the directions stated here https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account.

1. write "please delete me" in your profile about section ***(only do this for the sites you don't want an account on anymore)***
2. go to the */contact* page and select that you need to delete your user profile, and submit it.